# HTTP Error 413 when reading online data with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, urllib

I'm using pandas `read_csv` to download and read a file to a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://some-monitor.com/rest/data', sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

Locally, the script works fine and the data is read to the dataframe. However, when I `ssh` into a remote server and run the script there, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 424, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 195, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = _urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 413:
```

Why is this occurring? Why does the script work locally but not on the server? The server's and my local OS are both the same: Ubuntu.

Comment: Does it work if you read it in chunks instead?

Comment: @FelipeLanza tried it with `chunksize` option too, and still the same error. Also tried `wget` and `curl`, with the same result

Comment: Try to download the file first. You can use the pretty-downloader library to download the file and then load it from your local computer.

Comment: @DeadSec, thanks! Your suggestion worked. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @DeadSec 's suggestion, the script now runs fine on the server too.
I used [pretty-downloader](https://pypi.org/project/pretty-downloader/) to first download the file, then load it in pandas.

```
from pretty_downloader import download
download('https://some-monitor.com/rest/data', file_name='my_file.csv')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
```